# using Dask library to merge two large dataframes

Tags: python, python-2.7, dask

I am very new to dask. I am trying to merge two dataframes (one in a small file that fits a pandas dataframe size but I'm using it as a dask dataframe for convenience, the other is really large). I try to save the result in a csv file since I know it might not fit in a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

AF=dd.read_csv("../data/AuthorFieldOfStudy.csv")
AF.columns=['AID','FID']

#extract subset of Authors to reduce final merge size
AF = AF.loc[AF['FID'] == '0271BC14']

#This is a large file 9 MB
PAA=dd.read_csv("../data/PAA.csv")
PAA.columns=['PID','AID', 'AffID']

result = dd.merge(AF,PAA, on='AID')

result.to_csv("../data/CompSciPaperAuthorAffiliations.csv").compute()
```

I get the following error, and don't quite understand it:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6b2f889f44ff> in <module>()
     14 result = dd.merge(AF,PAA, on='AID')
     15 
---> 16 result.to_csv("../data/CompSciPaperAuthorAffiliations.csv").compute()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/core.pyc in to_csv(self, filename, **kwargs)
    936         """ See dd.to_csv docstring for more information """
    937         from .io import to_csv
--> 938         return to_csv(self, filename, **kwargs)
    939 
    940     def to_delayed(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/io/csv.pyc in to_csv(df, filename, name_function, compression, compute, get, **kwargs)
    411     if compute:
    412         from dask import compute
--> 413         compute(*values, get=get)
    414     else:
    415         return values

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/base.pyc in compute(*args, **kwargs)
    177         dsk = merge(var.dask for var in variables)
    178     keys = [var._keys() for var in variables]
--> 179     results = get(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    180 
    181     results_iter = iter(results)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/threaded.pyc in get(dsk, result, cache, num_workers, **kwargs)
     74     results = get_async(pool.apply_async, len(pool._pool), dsk, result,
     75                         cache=cache, get_id=_thread_get_id,
---> 76                         **kwargs)
     77 
     78     # Cleanup pools associated to dead threads

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/async.pyc in get_async(apply_async, num_workers, dsk, result, cache, get_id, raise_on_exception, rerun_exceptions_locally, callbacks, dumps, loads, **kwargs)
    491                     _execute_task(task, data)  # Re-execute locally
    492                 else:
--> 493                     raise(remote_exception(res, tb))
    494             state['cache'][key] = res
    495             finish_task(dsk, key, state, results, keyorder.get)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)

Traceback
---------
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/async.py", line 268, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/async.py", line 249, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/shuffle.py", line 329, in collect
    res = p.get(part)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/partd/core.py", line 73, in get
    return self.get([keys], **kwargs)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/partd/core.py", line 79, in get
    return self._get(keys, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/partd/encode.py", line 30, in _get
    for chunk in raw]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/partd/pandas.py", line 144, in deserialize
    for block, dt, shape in zip(b_blocks, dtypes, shapes)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/partd/numpy.py", line 127, in deserialize
    l = decode(l)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/partd/numpy.py", line 114, in decode
    return list(map(decode, o))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/partd/numpy.py", line 110, in decode
    return [item.decode() for item in o]
```

Comment: Can you try `pip install partd --upgrade` or `pip install dask --upgrade` generally to see if this resolves the issue?

Comment: @MRocklin I just installed partd and dask. So they are up to date. But just to double check I ran the above commands and `Requirement already up-to-date:`

Comment: In that case can you raise an issue at http://github.com/dask/partd/issues/new

Also, I suspect that this problem would not occur in Python 3